# how to fix my index page

Tags: php, mysql, session, home-directory

I'm new to php programming and I tried writing the index page for the admin login however it won't work can anybody tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

```
<?php
     session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
        header("location: admin_login.php"); 
        exit();
    }

    // Be sure to check that this manager SESSION value is in fact in the database
    $managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters

    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["manager"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters

    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Run mySQL query to be sure that this person is an admin and that their password   session var equals the database information

    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person

    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
     $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 0) { // evaluate the count
         echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
         exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you tell us the error you get, we might be able to help you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please explain what you mean by `won't work`? What doesn't work? What did you expect? What did you get instead?

Comment: You need to say what exactly is wrong, what error you get etc

Comment: you are checking your session manager in starting if it is set how your code will run after this.

Answer (score 0):

Please posrt all code including html form then we help u.
you miss else case
in else case use

```
if ($existCount == 0) { // evaluate the count
         echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
         exit();
    }

else{
$_SESSION["manager"]=$manager;

}
```